# UPDATE: dynamically replace the src attribute of embed tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, embed, movie

When I try to change the src attribute of embedded movie (quicktime), it strangely works locally in Firefox, but doesn't work on server in firefox, doesn't work in Safari either locally or on server, and it doesn't work in IE.

I try what was suggested below:

```
    $(".image_thumb ul li ul li").click(function(){     
var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href");  
var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html(); 
var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();   

if ($(this).is(".active")) {  
    return false; 
} else {
    alert(imgTitle);
    var videoClone = $(".main_image object").clone()
       .find("embed").attr({src: imgTitle}).end()  
       .find("param:first").attr({value: imgTitle});
    $(".main_image object").remove();
    $(".main_image").append(videoClone);

    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
        $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );

    });
}
//more code
```

This doesn't make the movie appear at all. Everything gets loaded but movie. Anyone know why? Surely, I can't be the only one using something other than flash to load movies.

html (if helpful):

```
<div id="vid_wrapper">
    <div class="main_image">
        <object width="160" height="144"
        classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
        codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
        <param name="src" value="../images/Intro-1.mov">
        <param name="autoplay" value="true">
        <param name="controller" value="false">




        <EMBED SRC="../images/Intro-1.mov" WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=380 AUTOPLAY=true CONTROLLER=true LOOP=false PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"> <!--    <img src="" alt="video_1"> -->
        </object>


        <div style="display: block;" class="desc">
            <a href="#" class="collapse">Close Me!</a>
            <div style="opacity: 0.85; margin-bottom: 0px; display: block;" class="block">
                    <h2>Video 1</h2>
                    <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="demo lists image_thumb">
            <ul>
              <li class="expand">Admin System
                <ul class="collapse">
                  <li class="active"> 

            <a href="../images/Intro-1.mov">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_1">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 1</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>    
                  <li>
            <a href="../images/Intro-2.mov">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_2">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 2</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
                </ul>

              </li>
              <li class="expand">Enrollment System
                <ul class="collapse">
                  <li>
            <a href="../images/Intro-1.mov">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_3">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 3</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>    

                  <li>
            <a href="video4.jpg">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_4">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 4</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="expand">Inventory System
                <ul class="collapse">

                  <li>
            <a href="video5.jpg">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_5">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 5</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>

                  <li> 
            <a href="video6.jpg">
                <img src="../images/banner1_thumb.jpg" alt="video_6">
            </a>
            <div class="block">
                <h2>Video 6</h2>
                <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>

                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with embedded objects, but I'm guessing that the browser doesn't respond to changes to the src attribute after it has been loaded.

No idea if this will work but try cloning the object, removing the existing one, changing the attributes on the cloned object, and then adding it back into the document.

Something like this:

```
var videoClone = $(".main_image object").clone()
   .find("embed").attr({src: imgTitle}).end()  
   .find("param:first").attr({value: imgTitle});
$(".main_image object").remove();
$(".main_image").append(videoClone);
```

Comment: It didn't work. THe movie itself now doesn't get loaded on page.In my initial question, I updated it.

Comment: Placing the movie in divs was the only solution. You cannot dynamically change the src attribute of embed tags in JavaScript. There's a new problem. The movie is layered over everything else in page, even though I have a menu that animates that should be in front of it.

Comment: Tried setting the z-index of the menu? E.g. to 100.

Comment: Yes I tried that. I set parent div of the two to relative. Set the movie div to 99 and set the menu div to 100. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the Parameter wmode="transparent" and then do the z-index thing..